# Repeat Function N times error

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

In haskell, I tried this:

```
multi::(Num n)=>n->((a->a)->(a->a))
(multi 0) f x=x
(multi n) f x=(multi n-1) f (f x)
```

Hoping to get a function that would repeat another function a number of times.
In ghci I got this:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( pad.hs, interpreted )

pad.hs:2:8:
    Could not deduce (Eq n) arising from the literal `0'
    from the context (Num n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 multi :: Num n => n -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
      at pad.hs:1:8-35
    Possible fix:
      add (Eq n) to the context of
        the type signature for multi :: Num n => n -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
    In the pattern: 0
    In an equation for `multi': multi 0 f x = x

pad.hs:3:23:
    Could not deduce (Num ((a -> a) -> a -> a))
      arising from a use of `-'
    from the context (Num n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 multi :: Num n => n -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
      at pad.hs:1:8-35
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Num ((a -> a) -> a -> a))
    In the expression: multi n - 1
    In the expression: (multi n - 1) f (f x)
    In an equation for `multi': multi n f x = (multi n - 1) f (f x)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I am a newbie to haskell. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost did it. A minimal fix is to add parentheses around `n - 1` and remove the signature:

```
(multi 0) f x=x
(multi n) f x=(multi (n-1)) f (f x)
```

Comment: Very nice for brevity. The other questions did put in their code, but you were the only one to explicitly say to do `(n-1)` instead of `n-1`.

Answer (score 4):

Couple things.  You can't check `Num` s for equality.  You are probably looking for an `Int`.  Second you don't need the parantheses around multi and it's argument. And some other formatting.

```
multi :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
multi 0 f x = x
multi n f x = multi (n-1) f (f x)
```

You could make this type signature more generic, but we will just stick with that.  But you can write this whole thing with higher order functions.

```
multi :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
multi n f a = foldl (\v _ -> f v) a [1..n]
```

Comment: In your second implementation, wouldn't foldr be more lazy?

Answer (score 2):

The smallest change I can make to your program that makes it compile is:

```
multi::(Eq n, Num n)=>n->((a->a)->(a->a))
(multi 0) f x=x
(multi n) f x=(multi (n-1)) f (f x)
```

The `Num` type class doesn't require members to already be members of `Eq`, so we have to specify that as well. Additionally, we want to pass `n-1` as an argument to `multi`.

This problem is normally done in Haskell land with `iterate` and `!!`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong here.

`Num n` does not imply `Eq n`, meaning there is no `Eq n => Num n` constraint in the `Num` typeclass definition.  In order to pattern match on `0` you need the `n` type to be an instance of `Eq`.  I would just explicitly change this to `Int`, there is no reason for the extra generality in this piece of code.

Next, `(multi n-1)` applies `multi` to `n` then subtracts `1`.b  I've also cleaned up the code and put the parens in the right places.

```
multi:: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
multi 0 _ x = x
multi n f x = multi (n-1) f (f x)
```

As [Cirdec points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19716875/166732) you can do this with `iterate f a !! n`.

Edit:

If what you're trying to do is get a function that is `f` applied `n` times you can do something like this.  Replacing `10` with `n` and `(1+)` with whatever function you wanted repeated.  (or just partially apply `multi`)

```
let f = foldr1 (.) (take 10 $ repeat (1+))
```

Comment: Also, I conceptually think of it as "multiplying a function." I then define this function. If I used it, it would be just passing the repeated function.

Comment: The line in the error message is incorrect.  `(multi n - 1)` applies `multi` to `n` then subtracts `1` from the result.  i.e. tries to subtract 1 from a partially applied function.  Note that I changed it to `multi (n - 1)`.

Comment: `->` is right associative, so the type signature `Int->(a->a)->a->a` is actually the same as `Int->((a->a)->(a->a))`.

Comment: I know, it just fits with my conceptions when I right it out.

Comment: Also, that worked. I forgot to put `n-1` in parenthesizes. How does order of operations work in Haskell?

Comment: @PyRulez Can you be more specific?  Function application binds more tightly than anything else.  Mathematical operator precedence is what you're used to.

Comment: Ah, okay. What is - called then?

Comment: From the standard prelude, `infixl 6  +, -`. So the `-` operator is left-associative and binds less tightly than multiplication and division operators (7) and function application (which is effectively 10). Addition and subtraction bind tighter than `:` list construction, which is effectively 5. The standard prelude from the report: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1710009 Infix keywords: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#infix.2C_infixl.2C_infixr